# Why apps are launching slowly?

Tags: applications, performance, ram, processor

This issue happens on all of my devices no matter what operating system is on it. Apps launch slowly, however the resources monitor says that CPU and RAM are not busy that much.

For instance, I installed a resources monitor floating widget on my Sony Xperia M2. What I found out that before I tap on a big app like FaceBook, the CPU usage is 3% and there are 370MB free RAM available. Then when I tap on the FaceBook app, the CPU usage started to vary within the range of 50~60% and the free RAM was changing within the range 300~350MB. However the app was still laggy, unlike higher-end Sony phone like Xperia Z2.

Briefly, the question is, why my phone is not functioning as fast as a higher-end phone of the same OS and brand even though it has 40% free CPU and 300MB of free RAM, why isn't it using 80 or 90% of the processor and the same in RAM?

Comment: Why is your phone not performing as a higher end phone? You said it yourself, because it's a lower end phone. Xperia M2 has a low-end Snapdragon 400 chipset with a quad-core 1.2 GHz processor and only 1 GB of RAM. Xperia Z2 on the other hand has a Snapdragon 801 chipset with a 2.3 GHz quad-core processor with 3 GB of RAM.

Comment: You should read [this](http://www.androidcentral.com/ram-what-it-how-its-used-and-why-you-shouldnt-care) and [this blog post by Dianne Hackborn, Android Software Engineer](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html) to understand how RAM management and multi-tasking works on Android

Comment: You can always [root your phone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CN3I0L1g3gA) (and void your warranty) and remove bloatware, install a custom ROM or a performance oriented kernel, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable answer is the speed of the NVRAM (or hard drive).

When an application loads, it needs to read the application into memory - Hard drives and sd cards (but not so much SSD cards) are very slow to read and write, and this is most likely the bottleneck.

A typical hard drive has a read speed of 100 Megabytes per second and SD card can vary greatly but would be typically much slower then a hard drive.  I have been unable to find the type of built in storage in the M2, but it looks like a very budget phone (540x960 pixels) so I imagine they have skimped on the speed of the storage on it to keep the price down.   That said, if you are running apps from an SD card, you may benefit (speedwise) from moving them back to the internal storage, or investing in higher speed sd card.  (A class 4 card is a LOT slower then a class 10 SD card)

Comment: thanks,
- are there more factors that affect the speed other than NVRAM?
- how to know what class is my SD card?
- for PC (since it happens on PC as well): if i bought black western digital hard disk will it consume the full capabilities of ram and cpu?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of factors.   On a lot of sdcards there is a number in a circle.  Normally 4,6 or 10.  That is the class of card.  That said, there is lots of variance within classes, so the best thing to do is to test by timing copies of large files to and from the cards.  Things like memory and CPU will also affect performance.  Your performance will depend on your type of workload - if you are doing a lot of disk reading and writing you need a decent disk, if most of it is number crunching or in-memory editing (eg a static image which fits in ram), then the hard disk is less important.

Comment: i always close unused opened apps so when i reopen them they need to go from the HDD to the RAM again so i'm doing a lot of disk reading and writing. does the motherboard have anything to do with speed?

Comment: Practically speaking motherboards have minimal influence on speed. Your best speedups generally come from a faster disk, more RAM (up to a point) and a faster CPU.

Comment: ceeeewwl thx alot